# Correct way to copy branches - git

Tags: git

I have two branches: **branch_a** and **branch_b**. I want all changes/commits of **branch_b** in **branch_a**. Also removing the previous commits/state of **branch_a**.

I have two options:

1. `git checkout branch_a` **and** `git reset --hard branch_b`
2. `git branch -D branch_a` **and** `git checkout -b branch_a branch_b`

Which option is better and why? Or Is there any better way to copy branches. **Note:** I just want **branch_a** to be a copy of **branch_b**.

Comment: I'm not even sure your second option would work since you're deleting `branch_a` before you try to use it for copying.  Other than this deletion step, both are very similar.  Also, your use of `sync` is misused IMO.  I think synching should be used in the context of pulling and pushing.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen The second would also work; it would first delete `branch_a`, then recreate it on the commit that `branch_b` points to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two options are mostly identical, in that you end up with both `branch_a` and `branch_b` pointing to the same commit (which `branch_b` already pointed to before).

The only difference that comes to my mind is that if you `reset` the branch label, this action will be recorded in its reflog, whereas if you delete and then recreate it, the previous reflog of `branch_a` will be lost.